# SQL injection is not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

I'm trying to perform an SQL injection on a dummy website created on my localhost for a security testing project.

I tried to enter the string `" OR "='` into the username and password field so it should bypass it and display *Login Correct* - But instead it displays *login failed*

Any help to understand why SQL injection is not working

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db('test');

    if(isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password'])){
       $username =$_POST['username'];
       $password = $_POST['password'];
       echo $username;
       echo $password;

       if(!empty($username)&&!empty($password)){
          $query ="SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
          $query_run = mysql_query($query);

          if(mysql_num_rows($query_run)>=1){
              echo 'Login Correct';
          }else{
              echo 'Login Failed';
          }
       }
    }
?>
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
   Username: <input type="text" name="username">
   Password: <input type="text" name="password">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Probably a magic quotes issue

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your injection string should be like this:

Username and password:

```
' or '1' = '1
```

Username (often) or password: (It depends on which one come first in the query)
`#` comments rest of the query.

```
' or '1'='1' #
```

For more information about SQL injection, you can check out this perfect url:
 [The SQL Injection Knowledge Base](http://www.websec.ca/kb/sql_injection#MySQL_Default_Databases)

Comment: ...There's the right one.  The `#` is important. Otherwise the injection would have to be in the `password` field.

Answer (score 3):

Try injecting this: `' or '1' = '1' --`

`'1' = '1'` is always true and `--` says everything after the `--` is an comment and won't be checked.

Comment: I've found that in some db implementations (mysql in particular) you need to have a space before the -- otherwise it isn't counted as a comment.